# React Infinite Render or Handler Never Called When Connecting to DB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, async-await

I'm trying to connect to my DB using async/await. When using the below code, the function `handleConnectToDB` never seems to be called, produces a white screen where the App as a whole never renders, or produces a React infinite render error. Ideally I want this handler to run every time the user goes to or refreshes the page, however I only want it to run once, not on re-renders.

- Calling `handleConnectToDB()` standalone: **Infinite Render Error**
- Calling `React.useEffect(handleConnectToDB());` : **Infinite Render Error**
- Calling `React.useEffect(handleConnectToDB);` : **App never renders (white screen)**
- Calling `React.useEffect(() => handleConnectToDB);` : **App + component renders. Handler never called.**
- Calling `React.useEffect(() => handleConnectToDB());` : **App never renders (white screen)**
- Calling `React.useEffect(() => {handleConnectToDB()}, []);` : **App + component renders. Handler never called.**
- Calling `React.useEffect(() => {handleConnectToDB()}, [handleConnectToDB]);` : **App + component renders. Handler never called.**

I threw in some `console.log()` statements to check and see if the handler is ever being called, and none of them have printed on any of the above. I imagine the error is somewhere in the handler function since all iterations of `React.useEffect()` produce some version of an error. I just can't figure out what would be causing an infinite error. I also imagine I've made a very silly mistake somewhere that I can't find.

**Update 1**: The infinite render error occurs when `dispatchSignUpState({
type: 'DB_CONNECT_INIT', payload: ''})`
is called. I don't understand why this is causing a re-render of the App when the state is local to the component.

```
const SignUpReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DB_CONNECT_INIT':
            return {
                ...state,
                isDBConnecting: true,
                isDBConnected: false,
                isDBError: false,
                querySelectors: action.payload
            };

        case 'DB_CONNECT_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                isDBConnecting: false,
                isDBConnected: true,
                isError: false
            };

        case 'DB_CONNECT_FAILURE':
            return {
                ...state,
                isDBConnecting: false,
                isDBConnected: false,
                isDBError: true,
                errorMessage: action.payload
            }

        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
  };
const SignUpPage = () => {
    //SET UP STATE REDUCER
    const [signUpState, dispatchSignUpState] = React.useReducer(
        SignUpReducer,
        {
            querySelectors: [],
            errorMessage: '',
            isDBConnecting: false, 
            isDBConnected: false, 
            isDBError: false
            }
    );

    //connect to the database
    const handleConnectToDB = React.useCallback(async () => {
        console.log("Debug: handleConnectToDB called.");
        dispatchSignUpState({
            type: 'DB_CONNECT_INIT',
            payload: '',
        });

        console.log('Beginning connection attempt...');

        try {
            console.log("Attempting to connect to DB...");
            await mongoose.connect( //await connection to mongoDB
                '<MYMONGOURI>', 
                {useNewUrlParser: true}
            );
            const db = mongoose.connection;
            db.once('open', () => {
                dispatchSignUpState({type: 'DB_CONNECT_SUCCESS'}); //change SignUpState: DB connection was sucessful.
            })

        } catch {
            dispatchSignUpState({
                type: 'DB_CONNECT_FAILURE',
                payload: 'Unable to connect to the server.',
            });
        }    
      }, []
    );

    React.useEffect(() => {
        handleConnectToDB()}, [handleConnectToDB]);
```

Comment: did you try remove "dispatchSignUpState" call inside "handleConnectToDB" as a test?

Comment: @Gustavo Graupner Yes, removing the dispatcher from the function removes the errors. I can't figure out what about the dispatched states is causing the errors however.